# Why this SSH command on Nexpect does not work?

Tags: node.js, ssh, expect, docker

I am trying to run and get information about docker containers from inside a docker container, to do this I am using Nexpect, but I found a strange error:

```
exports.getIP = function(username, callback){
   var nexpect = require('nexpect');
   nexpect.spawn("ssh core@172.17.8.101 \"docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' " + username + "\"")
         .expect(" ")
         .run(function (err, stdout, exitcode) {
             if (err) {
                 callback(err);
             }
           console.log("inside = " + stdout);
           ip = stdout;

           callback(null, ip);
    });
};
```

The error response for this method is "Error : Command not found: ssh"

But if I manually run in the shell:

```
ssh core@172.17.8.101 "docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' test"
```

Works perfectly.

I also have very similar functions to run Docker using the Nexpect and SSH and it is working fine. After some tests I think it is something with the \ character but for this specific command I have to use quotation marks on the string.

Comment: Have you tried running it from it's directory? `/usr/bin/ssh` for example.

Comment: I just tried and got: "Error: Command not found: /usr/bin/ssh", I tried it on the command shell and worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ssh2 module](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) instead of spawning a child process and using `nexpect`:

```
var Connection = require('ssh2');

var ssh = new Connection();
ssh.on('ready', function() {
  ssh.exec("docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' test", function(err, stream) {
    if (err)
      throw err;

    stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
      console.log('>> Docker exited with code %d, signal %s', code, signal);
    }).on('close', function() {
      // this indicates that there is no more stdout/stderr output,
      // just like with node's spawn()
      ssh.end();
    }).pipe(process.stdout);

    stream.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
  });
}).connect({
  host: '172.17.8.101',
  username: 'core',
  agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
  // or if you have a specific key you want to use:
  //privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync(process.env.HOME + '/.ssh/id_rsa')
});
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error: Disconnected by host (PROTOCOL_ERROR): Packet integrity error. After some research I failed in fix it, I am using the privateKey way.

Comment: Using the agent way I got the error: Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake